# Calculate videoHeight relative to videoWidth (aspect-ratio) plus 30px - JavaScript

Tags: height, aspect-ratio, calc

I have a specific video-player which is embedded with an iframe. It has a toolbar at the bottom with a fixed height of 30px.

The video-width is scaled within a bootstrap framework and I want to calculate the height based on the current width.

Like: videoHeight = (videoWidth * 0.5625) + 30px

The value 0.5625 is based on 16*9 aspect-ratio.

Now have I tried the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var wide = $('#video-container').css('width');
   var calculate = parseInt(wide, 10) * 0.5625;
   var videoheight = calculate + 30;

   $('#video-container').css('height', videoheight);
});
```

It works partially, it does calculate the aspect-ratio correctly but it does not add the 30px. Can anybody tell me where I'm going wrong?